# CSS align left, right, and repeating middle

Tags: css

I have a `.png` for the left and right, and a third to repeat across the (unknown) width of the window.

```css
#wrap{
    width: 100%;
    height: 10px;
}
#a{
    float: left;
    background-color: #800000;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
}
#b{
    background-color: #008000;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    height: 10px;
}
#c{
    float: right;
    background-color: #000080;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="a">
    </div>
    <div id="b">
    </div>
    <div id="c">
    </div>
</div>
```

Like this, the `float: right` element is on a second line, as it were.

If I add `display: inline` (or ~`-block`) to the middle element, it doesn't display but th left/right are fine.

What's wrong?

Comment: He needs to specify the "Height" attribute of A, B, and C. I'm working on it right now :)

Comment: Oh crap I didn't hit update. It was working as described.. Working (in the sense that it doesn't work, but demonstrates my problem) fiddle linked now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Floating elements have to be placed before the non-floating content in the HTML code, even if they float at the right. So, place #c before #b in HTML.

Comment: @Huangism beat you, but +1 for telling me *why*. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this, I rearranged the html

http://jsfiddle.net/sKqZJ/128/

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="a"></div>
    <div id="c"></div>
    <div id="b"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You gotta be kidding. Wow. Thanks!

Comment: yea floats before static, welcome to the wonderful world of floats